# Firebase hosting rewriting issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am hosting a React website on firebase hosting, with following file structure.

```
...
/static
/public
 ...
 privacy.html
 index.html
```

Whenever I visit to any url line `/dashboard`, `/profile` or anything, looks like firebase rewriting everything to `index.html` which is fine in most of my use case.

But now I have different use case. I have file with name `privacy.html` inside public directory. I want to open that html file only when user visits `MY_APP_DOMAIN.com/privacy.html`.

I don't want to handle it in frontend because the `privacy.html` file is simple optimized static html and I dont want to load react js bundle first for loading that.

In localhost, its working fine. So, It must be the problem with firebase hosting. Please guide me how can i fix this.

Answer (score 1):

not sure that i got you correctely but if you want to use following

> [**Configure rewrites**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites)
>
> Optional Use a rewrite to show the same content for multiple URLs.
> Rewrites are particularly useful with pattern matching, as you can
> accept any URL that matches the pattern and let the client-side code
> decide what to display.
>
> You can also use rewrites to support apps that use HTML5 pushState for
> navigation. When a browser attempts to open a URL path that matches
> the specified source or regex URL pattern, the browser will be given
> the contents of the file at the destination URL instead.
>
> **Specify URL rewrites by creating a rewrites attribute that contains an array of objects (called "rewrite rules"). In each rule, specify a
> URL pattern that, if matched to the request URL path, triggers Hosting
> to respond as if the service were given the specified destination
> URL.**

try adding following

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/privacy.html",
        "destination": "/privacy.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

ref [full-config#firebase-json_example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example)

Comment: I tried the same but it doesn't worked. I tried using redirect and it works in that case but what if I don't want my url to change like in case of rewrite. And Thank You for answers.